# Trigger a Lua action when pressing a key on a keyboard in Logitech G Hub

Tags: lua, macros, keyboard-events, key-bindings, logitech

I have a Logitech G502 mouse and a G213 keyboard, and I'm looking for a way to activate an action in Lua by pressing a key.
Researching and looking for information on the matter, I found that the solution was to use "event == "KEY_PRESSED ", But it didn't work, I tested to see if there was any response with this code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if event == "G_PRESSED" then
    OutputLogMessage("G key pressed\n")
  elseif event == "M_PRESSED" then
    OutputLogMessage("Mouse button pressed\n")
  elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" then
    OutputLogMessage("Mouse button %d pressed\n", arg)
  elseif event == "KEY_PRESSED" then
    OutputLogMessage("Keyboard key %d pressed\n", arg)
    end
end
```

I'm only getting response from the G502 mouse in the console

I also tried with this code and got the same results as the previous code, only the buttons on the G502 mouse and the F1...F12 keys.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
end
```

I am searching and trying ways to activate actions with the other keys on the keyboard apart from the F1...F12 keys, which are currently working.

Comment: `M_PRESSED` is for special M-keys (on some Logitech keyboards), M-keys are absent on G213.

Answer (score 0):

Only G-keys (F1..F12) generate events when pressed.
Usual keys (letters, digits) do not.
This was done on purpose to make impossible a keylogger in LGS/GHub Lua, because these scripts are subject to share between players, so they should be safe.
Nobody uses keys F1..F12 in a password, so F1..F12 events are ok to be stolen :-)

You can also receive modifier keys current statuses (Alt, Ctrl, Shift) and LED lamp current  statuses (CapsLock, ScrollLock, NumLock), but not their press/release events.